# Mysql Error PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql xetasi: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ssssss', konu_onay = '1', konu_ekleyen = '1', konu_anasayfa = ' at line 4
please help

my code

```
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <article class="module width_full">
        <header><h3>Kateqoria Elave et</h3></header>
        <?php 

        if ($_POST){

            $konu_basliq = p("konu_basliq");
            $konu_link = sef_link($konu_basliq);
            $konu_kategori = p("konu_kategori");
            $konu_anasayfa_aciklama = p("konu_anasayfa_aciklama");
            $konu_full_aciklama = p("konu_full_aciklama");
            $konu_aciklama =  p($konu_anasayfa_aciklama."-------------------------------".$konu_full_aciklama);
            $konu_etiket = p("konu_etiket");
            $konu_onay = p("konu_onay");
            $konu_anasayfa = p("konu_anasayfa");
            $konu_ekleyen = session("uye_id");

        if (!$konu_basliq || !$konu_full_aciklama || !$konu_anasayfa_aciklama){
            echo '<h4 class="alert_error">Lazim olan yerleri doldurun !</h4>';
        }else{
            $varmi = query("SELECT * FROM yazilar WHERE konu_link = '$konu_link'");
            if (mysql_affected_rows()){
                echo '<h4 class="alert_error"><strong>'.ss($konu_basliq).'</strong>Adli Yazi artiq var </h4>';
            }else{
                $insert = query("INSERT INTO yazilar SET 
                konu_basliq = '$konu_basliq',
                konu_kategori = '$konu_kategori',
                konu_link = '$konu_link,
                konu_aciklama = '$konu_aciklama',
                konu_etiket = '$konu_etiket',
                konu_onay = '$konu_onay',
                konu_ekleyen = '$konu_ekleyen',
                konu_anasayfa = '$konu_anasayfa'");
                if ($insert){
                    echo '<h4 class="alert_success">Yazi elave edildi</h4>';
                    go(URL. "/admin/index.php?do=yazilar", 1);
                }else{
                    echo '<h4 class="alert_error">Mysql xetasi: '.mysql_error().'</h4>';
                }
            }
        }

        }

        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="module_content">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Yazi Adi</label>
                        <input type="text" name="konu_basliq" />
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                        <label>Kategoria</label>
                        <select name="konu_kategori">
                        <?php

                    $katQuery = query("SELECT * FROM kategoriler ORDER BY  kategori_adi ASC");
                    while ($katRow = row($katQuery)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$katRow["kategori_id"].'">'.ss($katRow["kategori_adi"]).'</option>';
                    }

                        ?>
                        </select>
                        </fieldset>


                        <fieldset>
                        <label>Yazi Esas Sehife acixlamsasi</label>
                        <textarea rows="3" name="konu_anasayfa_aciklama"></textarea>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                        <label>Yazi Full acixlamsasi</label>
                        <textarea rows="10" name="konu_full_aciklama"></textarea>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                        <label>Yazi Etiketleri</label>
                        <input type="text" name="konu_etiket" />
                        </fieldset>

                            <fieldset>
                        <label>Yazi Testiqi</label>
                        <select name="konu_onay">
                        <option value="1"selected>Testiqli</option>
                        <option value="0">Testiq olunmayib</option>
                        </select>
                        </fieldset>

                                <fieldset>
                        <label>Yazi Esas Sehifede Gorsensin ?</label>
                        <select name="konu_anasayfa">
                        <option value="1"selected>Beli</option>
                        <option value="0">Xeyir</option>
                        </select>
                        </fieldset>




            </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="submit_link">

                <input type="submit" value="Yazi elave Et" class="alt_btn">

            </div>
        </footer>
        </form>
    </article><!-- end of post new article -->

            </div>
    </article><!-- end of styles article -->
    <div class="spacer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a single quote on the following line:

```
konu_link = '$konu_link,
```

It should be:

```
konu_link = '$konu_link',
```

You're also vulnerable to SQL injection, see: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)